Mi laptop no prende ni carga
Cordial saludo chicos y chicas
Disculpen la molestia, el problema rige en que mi compu lo deje descargado hasta el 0% y no lo cargue ni prendí por tres dias y el dia de hoy lo fui a prender y cargar y no enciende ya han pasado horas conectado y no realiza ninguna accion ni presionando el boton encendido ni cambiando de enchufe.
Les estare agradecida por la solucion a este problema y si definitivamente tengo que recurrir a un tecnico para poder arreglar mi compu.
El computador es marca asus tuf gaming a15

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la temética de la pregunta no está relacionada con la creación de software.

Hola yelithza hurtado definitivamente si no tienes experiencia para la reparación de casos similares deberías de recurrir a un técnico ya que algunas de las pruebas que debes realizar para descartar el daño de la batería o algún otro componente electrónico debes abrir el equipo sin causar mayores daños y revisar si retirando la batería logra encender lo otro seria revisar la entrada y salida de corriente del puerto de carga en la tarjeta madre ambos procedimientos requieren abrir el equipo

Lee [answer], en especial la sección Contesta preguntas bien formadas. Además, cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios en las preguntas.

Dale ya agende una cita con el tecnico, muchas gracias por ayudarme☺️
